# How to mimic multiple returns for reused api call using pytest

Tags: python, python-unittest, side-effects

I'm trying to test a function that looks like this that calls an SDK.

FUNCTION TO BE TESTED

```
def create_folder_if_not_exists(
        sdk: looker_sdk,
        folder_name: str,
        parent_id: str) -> dict:

    folder = sdk.search_folders(name=folder_name)

    if folder or parent_id == '1':
        folder = folder[0]
        raise Exception(
            f"Folder {folder_name} already exists or is a reserved folder")
    else:
        parent_id = sdk.search_folders(name=parent_id)[0].id

        logger.info(f'Creating folder "{folder_name}"')
        folder = sdk.create_folder(
            body=models.CreateFolder(
                name=folder_name,
                parent_id=parent_id
            )
        )
    return folder
```

The test that i'm writing has to be able to mock the `search_folders` endpoint in two different ways, first passing no value, then passing a value for the else condition, which should return an `id` field. The library i've been using is pytest and trying to use side effects but i'm fairly new to testing and not sure how to do this. My current code is as follows

###### Creating a few mock objects that mimic the api structure

```
class MockSDK():
    def search_folders(self):
       pass
    def create_folder(self):
       pass

class MockSearchFolder():
    def __init__(self, parent_id, name):
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.name = name

class MockCreateFolder():
    def __init__(self, parent_id, folder_name):
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.folder_name = folder_name
```

###### Defining a side_effect with two values where I return the side effects

```
def mock_search_folder(**kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('folder_name') == 'googn':
            return None
        else:
            return MockSearchFolder(parent_id='frankie fish', name='nice guy eddie')



def test_create_folder_if_not_exists():
    # Tests the creation of a folder if it doesn't exist or have a parent id of 1
    sdk = MockSDK()
    tt = MockSearchFolder(name='dd', parent_id='dddd')
    with unittest.mock.patch.object(sdk, 'search_folders', side_effect=mock_search_folder) as sf:

        test = fc.create_folder_if_not_exists(
            sdk=sdk, folder_name='googn', parent_folder_name='4')
        assert test == 'frank'
```

I don't think i'm passing return values in the with statement, but perhaps i'm wrong.

Would anyone be able to take a glance at this and tell me what i'm doing wrong ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update, i think i've been overthinking this, defining the side_effects as an array did the trick, enabling the first call to be returned as `None` and the second returned as my mock object.

```
def test_create_folder_if_not_exists_xyz(mocker):
    # Tests the creation of a folder if it doesn't exist or have a parent id of 1
    sdk = MockSDK()
    sf_data = None
    sf_data1 = [MockSearchFolder(name='frank', parent_id=4, id=55)]
    mocker.patch.object(sdk, 'search_folders', side_effect=[sf_data, sf_data1])

    test = fc.create_folder_if_not_exists(
        sdk=sdk, folder_name='googn', parent_folder_name='4')
    assert test == 'frank'
```